# a little riddle, prime numbers and modulo

Tags: number-theory

Is there a prime number $k$ , such that $k$  is not $1\bmod3$ , not $2
\bmod4$ , not $3\bmod5$ , not $5
bmod7$ etc..
Meaning, $k$ is not $n\bmod(n+2)$ for any $n=1,....,100000000$ ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're looking for such a prime? Or is it just a question you thought of yourself, and you're curious as to whether it has an answer, and what that answer might be? What's special about 100000000?

Comment: Ignoring the requirement about primeness, letting $N=100000000$, you do have $N!-1$ satisfies all of the congruences listed, it instead being $2\pmod{3}, 3\pmod{4}, 4\pmod{5}$ etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz and is also not $0 \pmod 2$

Comment: Right.  I could have said instead $N!$, which *also* satisfies all of the congruences, it being $0\pmod{2},0\pmod{3},0\pmod{4},\dots$ but that number is very obviously not prime.  Figuring out whether $N!-1$ is prime or not is much harder, or if $N!\cdot k -1$ is prime for some $k$.  [The largest known factorial prime being $208003!-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime#:~:text=A%20factorial%20prime%20is%20a,%2B%201%20or%201!)

Comment: @JMoravitz Isn't the case of $N!\cdot k-1$ just the case of applying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions ?

Comment: @StinkingBishop sure seems like it, I'm not as well versed in theorems in number theory.  That, combined with my earlier comments should suffice as a proof.  It's surely not an optimally small prime that results, but it should suffice regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $100000000$ we will write $N$ to make this more general.

From [Dirichlet's theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) we can choose $p$ (your $k$) to be of the form $a(N+2)!-1$. Suppose $p \equiv m \pmod{m+2}$ for some $m \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$. Then $p+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{m+2}$, so $m+2 \mid p+2 = a(N+2)!+1$. But we also know that $m+2 \mid (N+2)!$, and that's a clear contradiction, so our $p$ satisfy the statement of the problem.

Comment: what is "$a"$ that multiplies $(N+2)!$?

Comment: Any positive integer, such that $a(N+2)!-1$ is a prime (we know about existence of such $a$ from Dirichlet's theorem).

Answer (score 2):

The lower of any pair of twin primes greater than your limit.

Specifically, for a limit of $100000000$, the prime $100000037 $ is two less than the prime $100000039 $ so fulfills your requirement.

Comment: That's good, but only works for more general cases if we know there are infinitely many twin prime pairs.

Comment: The twin prime conjecture is pretty solid though. Enormous primes have to start behaving in an unexpectedly coordinated fashion to invalidate it.

Comment: Solid? Certainly not as solid as Dirichlet.

Comment: I think the description "pretty solid" carries the idea of remaining doubt adequately.